# Propel returning same record multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I have a very simple database (MySql) with one table which I am accessing using Propel with this code...

```
<?php
$autoloader = require '/vendor/autoload.php';
$autoloader->add('', __DIR__ . '/generated-classes/');

use Propel\Runtime\Propel;
use Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionManagerSingle;

require './generated-conf/config.php';
require './includes/pagebuilder.php';

Propel::getConnection("default")->useDebug(true);

$videos = VideosQuery::create()
    ->orderByAddeddate()
    ->paginate($page = 1, $maxPerPage = 20);

echo GetMainPage($videos);
echo Propel::getConnection()->getLastExecutedQuery();
?>
```

The query seems to be generated correctly...

```
SELECT videos.id, videos.AddedDate, videos.Rating, videos.Views, videos.Title, videos.Description, videos.ImageUrl, videos.EmbedUrl FROM videos ORDER BY videos.AddedDate ASC LIMIT 20
```

If I run this query through phpMyAdmin I get the expected results, however, Propel seems to be returning the first record found by the query 20 times.  Anyone know what might be happening here?
Thanks

edit: Record loop

```
function GetMainContent($videos) {
    $mc = '<main>
            <div id="video-box-wrapper">';

    foreach($videos as $video) {
        $mc .= '<div class="video-box">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="' . $video->getImageUrl() . '" />
                        <span>' . $video->getTitle() . '</span>
                        <br />
                        <p>' . $video->getViews() . ' views</p>
                        <p>Rating: ' . $video->getRating() . '/10</p>
                    </a>
                </div>';
    }
    $mc .= '</main>';

    return $mc;
}
```

Comment: This looks like your retrieval code. Where's the part where you're getting twenty identical records?

Comment: When I loop through $videos each record is identical.  I have added code to the original question.

Comment: Does the query run manually produce the correct results? What does a [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) of `$videos` show?

Comment: Yes if I run query manually in phpmyadmin or mysql workbench I get the correct results.  var_dump of $videos shows 20 identical records in the data array.

Comment: Are you using the current version of Propel? Does this behaviour happen on other tables with similar queries? Don't forget that there's a lot of ways to [engage with the Propel community](http://propelorm.org/support.html) when encountering bizarre things like this.

Comment: Propel 2.0 installed with composer.

Comment: Solved. I had used propel init to generate a schema from the existing db, but not added a PK to the table until after the schema was generated.  I reran init and now all works fine.

Comment: Since this seems like a problem other people might have you could add an answer with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema I had generated from my existing database using propel's init command was created prior to setting a primary key for that table.  This caused Propel to return the same record multiple times in one query.
This was resolved by regenerating the schema with the primary key in place.